# Is Python or C# with ArcObjects more efficient in memory management in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I have two scripts one in Python and other in C# using ArcObjects, both of them perform same operations and that is making some edition by using Select by Location.

The amount of data which is being processed is large and while using the Python script I get an error stating Out of Memory, while the C# script works perfectly fine.

I have tried setting the flag link: https://gisgeek.blogspot.in/2012/01/set-32bit-executable-largeaddressaware.html?showComment=1498490022902#c7602920706364823811

Now the Python script does not display the memory error. Which brings to this question is C# really more efficient when it comes to memory management?

The version of ArcGIS Desktop I am using is 10.4.1

Comment: I think you should include Python and C# code snippets to illustrate what you are describing.

Comment: I've always understood that arcpy was essentially a wrapper to the underlying ArcObjects so it could be used in scripting with python. Sounds like you have discovered some sort of memory leak? But you do not state which version of ArcGIS you are using so may be it is fixed?